# How to lay one sprite on another in SFML?

Tags: c++, sprite, sfml

I want to write my own game, I began with SFML-library. Now I have one little problem: how can i do such thing: I have a background sprite and player's sprite. But figure of player isn't rectangle, it's more complicate. When I lay one sprite on another (on same position), I become some white space in rectangle of player. What should I write to place background instead white space?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need your player sprite be a picture type that supports transparency. Then make everything that's not the player transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. As stated by @nvoigt in the comments, you just use an image format that have a alpha channel (like PNG). Then you manually make every part you want transparent in a image editor.
2. You could use the [`sf::Image::createMaskFromColor`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#a22f13f8c242a6b38eb73cc176b37ae34) method. You only need to specify a color that will show as transparent.

If you go the route of `createMaskFromColor`, here's a snippet:

```
sf::Image image;
image.LoadFromFile("yourImage.bmp");
image.CreateMaskFromColor(sf::Color(0,255,255)); // for example, Cyan

// if you need that image into a texture
sf::Texture texture;
texture.LoadFromImage(image);

// to use sprite
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.SetTexture(texture);
```